# Devops Release Pipeline: What is the scope of a variable value set in a deployment group task using Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

The documentation I can find about the scope of variable values set using `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable` appears to revolve around build pipelines.

What is the scope in a release pipeline?

I have a release pipeline with 3 deployment groups.

The first sets variables as follows.

```
$now=$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmm");
"now: $now"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleasePipelineRunTime]$now"
```

That appears to set the variable as required. I can prove this by a subsequent powershell task which simply outputs the value of the variable to the pipeline logs.

I want to use in the following two deployment group tasks however in those deployment groups the variable resets back to it's default value.

Should the new value  be available in all tasks in subsequent deployment groups?

If not how does it get set so it can be?

I note there is an 'isoutput' option for task.setvariable but documentation around that states the variable needs to be used using a prefix but tasks do not appear to have id's so I'm not sure if it's relevant here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the scope of a variable value set in a deployment group task
> using Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable
> variable=ReleasePipelineRunTime]$now"

The variable is in a job scope. For the classic build pipeline, it is noted in the doc  [Set a multi-job output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable-1).
[image: You can't pass a variable from one job to another job of a build pipeline, unless you use YAML.]

It is the same for the classic release pipeline.

Workaround:
You can save the variable value to another place in the first job and then get it in the following jobs.

For example, create a variable group and use [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to update and get the  variable value.

[image]
[image]
In Job 1:

Powershell task 1 get time now and set the variable in task (job scope):

```
$now=$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmm");
"now: $now"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleasePipelineRunTime]$now"
```

Powershell task 2 update the variable ReleasePipelineRunTime in variable group with REST API:

```
$token = ""

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{VariableGroupID}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  
  "variables": {
    "ReleasePipelineRunTime": {
      "value": "$(ReleasePipelineRunTime)"
    }

  },
  "type": "Vsts",
  "name": "variable group1",
  "description": "Updated variable group"

}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

Powershell task 3 check the ReleasePipelineRunTime in the task (job scope)：

```
Write-Host $(ReleasePipelineRunTime)
```

Job 2:

Powershell task 1 get the value of ReleasePipelineRunTime in variable group with REST API and set the variable in the task (job scope):

```
$token = ""

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{VariableGroupID}?api-version=6.0-preview.2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
$name="ReleasePipelineRunTime"
$variablevalue =  $response.variables.$name.value

echo  $variablevalue
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleasePipelineRunTime]$variablevalue"
```

Powershell task 2 check the ReleasePipelineRunTime in the task (job scope)：

```
Write-Host $(ReleasePipelineRunTime)
```